# Installation problem on jdk1.7.0_11

Tags: java, openjdk, installation

I am trying to install my ubuntu using the downloaded jdk1.7.0_11 and jre1.7.0_11,and i traced the questions from here and followed tat steps even it is not installing the java.
In the terminal , I am getting an error like this

```
Selection    Path                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_11/bin/java   3         auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_11/bin/java   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_11/bin/java   3         manual mode


Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_11/bin/java because link group java is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java with a link.
```

pls guide me to work it possible to install java

Thank you

Comment: Its not an error message. its process of installation asking you to  give the choice, you need to select the option that corresponds to your package. And that is the final step of installation, there after you could give `$ java --version` in terminal to check what you have installed.

Comment: i even tried tat by giving one of those options ,but i couldnt able to see the installed version of java by using the java --version,i am getting The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
so i gave sudo apt-get install with the above packages it shows error as sridhar@sridhar-Satellite-A305:~$ sudo apt-get openjdk-6-jre-headless
E: Invalid operation openjdk-6-jre-headless

Comment: forgot to ask you, have you tried it from Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: yes that also i tried but its not installing :(

Answer (score 1):

As VRU said it is not an error, it is a selection. It appears when more than one version of a program is installed. In this case you can select which Java version is used to execute Java programs.

The top one is the presently selected. Below that all the options are listed. In this case you can choose between the JRE and the JDK. JRE is the Java Runtime Environment and is usually fine for running all Java programs. JDK is the Java Development Kit. It is mainly needed to compile Java programs. Some programming tools require to be run with the JDK instead of JRE. If you are not developing programs in Java, selecting the JRE is fine.

If you had Java 6 (or 5) installed alongside with Java 7, it would also appear in this list.

You can check the version using `java --version`. The selection can be changed later on with `sudo update-java-alternatives`. Try forcing this.

If it doesn't work reinstall the java packages. If you are not developing Java you could also remove the JDK entirely, making the selection obsolete.

Comment: i even tried tat by giving one of those options ,but i couldnt able to see the installed version of java by using the java --version,i am getting The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
so i gave sudo apt-get install with the above packages it shows error as sridhar@sridhar-Satellite-A305:~$ sudo apt-get openjdk-6-jre-headless
E: Invalid operation openjdk-6-jre-headless

Answer (score 0):

In my system I have installed **OpenJDK** in **offline mode** and it went successful. I am sharing you the same. Before you start, remove all old files so that you don't get in to any confusion and start with any one i.e., either JDK or JRE.

## Installation of OpenJDK on Ubuntu :

1)  Download OpenJDK

2)  Extract the tar file.(using any of the two steps)

```
      Right click on the .tar file and select Extract Here.

      or open Terminal and give the command tar –xzf <filename>
```

example:

```
           $ tar xzf jdk-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

3) Move the extracted file to the “**/usr/lib/jvm/**” folder: [Note: If you don’t find a jvm folder in /usr/lib/ path , create a jvm folder there: `$ sudo mkdir –p /usr/lib/jvm/`]

```
           $ sudo mv jdk1.7.0_07 /usr/lib/jvm/
```

4) Install in your system :

```
           $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javac 1
```

5) That’s it. Test your Java :

```
           $ java -version
```

Remember to replace the file name with the one you have downloaded.

Comment: oops !!! it doesnt work for me   /# sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_11/bin/javac 1
/# java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: nothing come...for ex: Empty directory with -ls command means wat would happen likewise printing again that ...this was happened 4th step :(

Comment: ok i will try im having that tar file also ...have to do same once again right??

Comment: actually my main aim is to install eclipse in ubuntu but it is asking me to download java so nly im doing

Comment: Yes. Even I have installed Open JDK for installing Eclipse on my machine, and I have done everything off-line.

Comment: nope the same error is coming :(

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless : Depends: tzdata-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: have you tried `sudo aptitude install openjdk-6-jre-headless` ? what was the out come?